# AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess (Provides full access...) equivalent?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm following a course on AWS Beanstalk that might be out of date. In IAM Management Console a user is added and one of the existing policies attached directly is `AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess`, which I cannot find while filtering policies myself.

Has this changed name? How can I find it or an equivalent?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess` was a managed IAM policy by AWS. They are now transitioning towards a new policy which is called `AdministratorAccess-AWSElasticBeanstalk`. Its not completely the same policy. If needed to follow along with your tutorial you could create the old `AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess` again. I would first try to use `AdministratorAccess-AWSElasticBeanstalk`.

If you want to read about the transition you can do that [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.managed-policies.html):

> Previously, Elastic Beanstalk supported two other managed user policies, AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess and AWSElasticBeanstalkReadOnlyAccess. We plan on retiring these previous policies. You might still be able to see and use them in the IAM console. Nevertheless, we recommend that you transition to using the new managed user policies, and add custom policies to grant permissions to custom resources, if you have any.

You can use [the waybackmachine](https://web.archive.org/web/20200714173126/http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.managed-policies.html) to copy over the old policy if needed

Comment: `eb update` results in `ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. Access Denied` for me with both `AdministratorAccess-AWSElasticBeanstalk` and `AWSElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdatesCustomerRolePolicy`

Comment: FWIW, I was missing `s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads` permission. I discovered this by running `eb <command> --debug`.

Comment: Great answer made even better by the wayback link to the old policy!

Comment: s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads worked, thanks